# How to get the auto-generated primary key after insertion in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My SQL Server table:

```
[dbo].[Rep] (
[rep_ID]        INT          IDENTITY (300, 1) NOT NULL,
[Restaurant_ID] INT          NULL,
[Fname]         VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Lname]         VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Rep_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rep_ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Restaurant_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Restaurant_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Restaurants] ([ID])
```

);

I want to create a stored procedure that return the auto generated key for the inserted record.

My current stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[createRepAcc]
    @first varchar(50),
    @last varchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Rep([Fname], [Lname])
    OUTPUT inserted.rep_ID
    VALUES (@first, @last);
```

It's able to insert into the table but only return 1 instead of the primary key generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something wrong with posted images.

Comment: Please don't post images of code (especially when those images are broken). As for the problem, I don't see anything wrong with your query.  When you run that `INSERT` it'll pass back the value of `rep_ID` for the row inserted in a dataset.

Comment: Your proc would not work because you are not inserting a value to `Restaurant_ID` and that column does not allow NULL.   Probably in an attempt to simplify the code you posted, you have obfuscated the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: If you change `Restaurant_ID` for be NULLable, your SP works fine: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a84b944bd4f4ac4f435e45e919ab17f). Either we're missing pieces of the puzzle, or...?

Comment: At a guess, *maybe* you're using `EXEC @Variable = {Stored Procedure};` syntax? If so, that might explain why. An SP returns the value `0` for a success and a non-zero value to indicate failure (which this would based on the information we have). Perhaps the failure is therefore causing the return value to be `1`. If you want to pass the value back of the inserted ID to a variable you should be using `OUTPUT` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **scope_identity()** to get the last generated id. For your case here is a detailed worksheet

```
/* creating a simple table with identity column */
CREATE TABLE dbo.a(identity_column INT IDENTITY(300,1), x CHAR(1));

/* Procedure that inserts values and returns generated output*/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ap]
    @x char(1),
    @id int output
AS
    INSERT INTO a(x) VALUES (@x);
    select @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

/* This is how the procedure could be called */
declare @ident int -- declare a variable to receive output
execute dbo.ap @x='b', @id=@ident output -- execute or call the procedure
select @ident -- select or print the genereated id
```